# Add "Please Select" to Drop-down list that retrieves values from Data base

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, drop-down-menu

I have a drop-down list and uses the SQL data source for it where I am retrieving the product names from SQL server. Now, I want to add "Please Select a product" Option to the drop-down list. 
As far as my knowledge, I add options to drop-down list by using

```
 <asp:ListItem Selected ="true" Value = "1">1</asp:ListItem>
```

Since, I am not adding the values but retrieving the values from DB, how to achieve this Option additionally and add to it as first position to my drop-down list?

I tried the below code, but not able to do get at first position.Also, each time I am getting extra "please select" option whenever I am selecting other values.

```
protected void NameDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
 NameDropDownList.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Please Select a product", "Please Select a product");
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ProductID, Price, Description, Rating FROM Product_Info Where Name = '" + NameDropDownList.Text + "'", conn);
 SqlDataReader myReader;
 conn.Open();
 myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
 while (myReader.Read()) {
 //Logic
}
  conn.Close();
  myReader.Close();
```

Here is my code behind where I bind the data:

```
 <tr>
     <td class="style2">Name</td>
      <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="NameDropDownList" runat="server" Height="16px" 
                Width="130px" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="NameSqlDataSource" 
                DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Name" 
                onselectedindexchanged="NameDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged">    
            </asp:DropDownList>

            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="NameSqlDataSource" runat="server" 
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ProductsConnectionString %>" 
                SelectCommand="SELECT [Name] FROM [Product_Info]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        </td>
</tr>
```

I also enables the Auto post back to true.Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add the code where you bind the `NameDropDownList` to your `DataSource` (I guess it's the one you want to add the message). The `SelectedIndexChanged` is definatly not the place to put it.

Comment: You should not be adding this item in the SeletedIndexChanged sub.  This will cause it to add a new list item each time the user selects a different item in the list.

Comment: @TonyHinkle I have updated the question. While adding this item in another , the event does not fires.

Comment: @GabrielGM Thanks for your comment and I have updated the question. You can see I bind the dropdown list to my data source in code behind. So I am getting error while adding that. what i am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your responses. I figured out the actual problem and able to done it in simple step.
First, I make the AppendDataBoundItems behavior of my drop-down list To TRUE and kept the following code and it works perfectly.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        { 
           NameDropDownList.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Please Select a Product", "Please Select a Product"));
        }

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Move this line `NameDropDownList.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Please Select a product", "Please Select a product");`
 t osomewhere after you bind your data, what is happening is that you insert this, then you bind over the top of it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you're using `asp:SqlDataSource`. You need to query and bind your data from the code because you want to manipulate it.

Here is the sample logic.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        // 1- Query into a list
        // 2- Add your custom item at the 1st position
        // 3- Set the DataSource of your list
        // 4- Make sure you bind your fields (text and value)
    }
}
```

I'll let you try the different steps above, but let me know if you have any trouble.